# how can i use WinJs.xhr in loops?

Tags: javascript, html, microsoft-metro

I want to call a url for 30 times and I used WinJS.xhr  in a for loop  but I am unable to get the response. And I tried the same url using Winjs.xhr outside the loop and i got the respone....can I use WinJs.xhr in loops?..pls help me with some example.

This was the code I tried.....

```
for (var i = 0; i < Ids.length; i++) 
{
    FromId[i] = data[i].id;;
    WinJS.xhr({ type: 'GET', url:"https://www.xyz.com/"+FromId[i] }).done(function (res) {
        sampleArray[i] = JSON.parse(res.responseText);
    });
}
```

If I use the below code outside the loop I was able see the response in res

```
WinJS.xhr({ type: 'GET',  url:"https://www.xyz.com/"+FromId[i] }).done(function (res) {
    sampleArray[i] = JSON.parse(res.responseText);
});
```

Comment: So, what have you tried? It'd help if you showed the code you have so we can fix it.

Comment: @sachleen:I tried the above code

Answer (score 0):

It seems pretty clear from this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br229787.aspx

that WinJS.xhr is just a simple wrapper around a JS AJAX call, and as such there should be no reason why running it inside a loop would cause it to break.  As other commentors have noted, it's virtually impossible to help you fix your problem with more information, but my guess is that you're expecting something work synchronously, and since this is an asychronous call you're not getting back the results you expected when you expected them.